# Assigning React element to a variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to assign a React component to a variable. The following code works

```
const TextField = ({multiline, ...props}) => {

 const InputElement = (p) => multiline ? <textarea {...p} /> : <input {...p}/>

 return <InputElement {...props} />

}
```

but it would cause recompute on re-rendering (and lint warnings :). Of course, I can use `useCallback()` to avoid it, but ideally, I'd like to say something like

```
const TextField = ({multiline, ...props}) => {

 const InputElement = multiline ? textarea : input

 return <>{InputElement(props)}</>

}
```

which of course does not compile. Is there a correct syntax to do it?

Comment: Just a note:  both version will end up doing the same, what do you mean by `recompute`.  The only difference is a wrapped function.   This is one of those LINT warning that's just totally pointless, and a `useCallback` would also be pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an UpperCamelCase variable name you can use it in your JSX directly like this:

```
const TextField = ({multiline, ...props}) => {
  const InputElement = multiline ? "textarea" : "input"

  return <InputElement {...props} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const TextField = ({multiline, ...props}) => {

 const inputElement = multiline ? <textarea {...props} /> : <input {...props}/>

 return <>{inputElement}</>

}
```

or

```
const TextField = ({multiline, ...props}) => {

 const inputElement = p => multiline ? <textarea {...p} /> : <input {...p}/>

 return <>{inputElement(props)}</>

}
```